# Protractor code is running fine on android phone but showing as failed in the report

Tags: android, protractor

I am running protractor code on android device. All the specs run as expected on the device but in the jasmine reporter is showing as failed.

Am facing this issue after I did **webdriver-manager update**

It is showing the below error:

> Failed: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"} (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.137) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

**This is my config file:**

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 300000,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',
specs: [
    './e2e/**/login.mobile.ts',
],
useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,


chromeDriver:'./node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe',

capabilities: {
    platformName: 'Android',
    platformVersion: '7.1.1', 
    deviceName: ''
    browserName: '', 
    autoWebview: true,
    autoacceptalerts: true,
    autoGrantPermissions: true,
    clearSystemFiles: true,

    app: './platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk',

},

plugins: [{
    path: require.resolve('protractor-console'),
    logLevels: ['severe'],
    package: 'jasmine2-protractor-utils',
    disableHTMLReport: false,
    disableScreenshot: false,
    screenshotPath: './screenshots',
    screenshotOnExpectFailure: true,
    screenshotOnSpecFailure: true,
    clearFoldersBeforeTest: true
}],


framework: 'jasmine2',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
    print: function () { }
},


beforeLaunch: function () {
    require('ts-node').register({
        project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
},
onPrepare() {
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        savePath: './report/mobile',
        filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
    }));
    var wd = require('wd'),
        protractor = require('protractor'),
        wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor, wd);
    wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);
},

onComplete: function () {
    var browserName, browserVersion;
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

    capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
        browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        browserVersion = caps.get('version');

        var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter');

        testConfig = {
            reportTitle: 'CVM Test Execution Report',
            outputPath: './report/mobile', //relative path
            screenshotPath: './screenshots',
            testBrowser: 'Mobile',
            browserVersion: browserVersion,
            modifiedSuiteName: false,
            screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true
        };
        new HTMLReport().from('./report/mobile/xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
    });
  }
};
```